# How to stop an image from moving after being changed by a javascript button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I`ve made a 2 buttons that run 2 functions to change the source of an image to a diffrent one. This works fine but whenever I change the source the image shifts slightly to the left and goes back to normal after changing source with the 2nd button back to the 1st image.

```js
function bulbon() {
  if (document.getElementById("lightbulb").src = "mini_mini_pngwing.com.png") {
    (document.getElementById("lightbulb").src = "mini_lightbulbon.png");
  }
}

function bulboff() {
  if (document.getElementById("lightbulb").src = "mini_lightbulbon.png") {
    (document.getElementById("lightbulb").src = "mini_mini_pngwing.com.png");
  }
}
```

```css
.lightbulb {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10%;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  left: 650px;
  top: 125px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="lightbulb">
    <img id="lightbulb" src="mini_mini_pngwing.com.png">
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="button" type="button" onclick="bulbon()">Turn On</button>
    <button id="button2" type="button" onclick="bulboff()">Turn Off</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

I tried to make a simple website with 2 buttons. One of them changes a lightbulb to be on, and another the lightbulb to be off. However for some reason the lightbulbs position changes whenever the 1st button is pressed and goes back to normal once the 2nd is pressed.

Comment: It sounds like the two images you are using are different sizes. Of course, we can't help confirm this unless you edit your question to include the images you're using. If they are different (intrinsic) sizes, you could style them to be a consistent size, remembering that you may need to style the size of both the wrapper `<div>` and the `<img>`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to program the whole thing on my computer and had the same problem. Then I put the light bulb images into gimp as two layers and found that they didn't overlap correctly. You may have exactly the same problem. I am sending two images showing it correctly. They are created from public domain image from https://freesvg.org/1434619451.

[light bulb on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYPEg.png)

[light bulb off image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ERtF.png)